# Как из array убрать NaN и поставить 0?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть datagridview на форме и массив который заполнен рандомными числами, с массива заполняется datagridview ,но некоторые строки отображаются как NaN. У массива и datagridview - тип float , подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать NaN из столбцов и поставить за место NaN - 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для проверки на NaN можно использовать метод Single.IsNaN() или сравнение с самим собой:

```
if (Single.IsNaN(array[i])) {
  array[i] = 0;
}

if (array[i] != array[i]) {
  array[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вдруг кому-то когда-то понадобится:

```
string s = grid1.Rows[m].Cells[n].Value.ToString(); //переводим датагрид в строку чтоб избавиться от нана
                
string s1 = s.Replace(("не число"), "0");//меняем нан на 0

array2[m, n] =int.Parse(s1); //переводим нашу строку в инт
```

Comment: Ваш метод полагается на текущую локаль. Если в системе будет другая локаль (ну, вдруг), то текст после `ToString` будет уже другой. Поэтому лучше всё-таки использовать универсальные методы из другого ответа.